# Postfix - Email Header from name

Tags: postfix

On an Ubuntu 12.04 server with installed postfix:
If I send an email from terminal with mail and look at the E-mail header.

From where does postfix generate the from name at this line:

Received: from **service.example.com** (service.example.com. [40.237.188.111])

I´ve looked at

- /etc/mailname
- /etc/hosts
- /etc/hostname
- /etc/postfix/main.cf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = …
```